# Using k-means clustering on web log data

Tags: apache, data-mining, k-means, access-log

I have a data set from a access web log file which I'm interested in finding similar clusters. (I'm an absolute beginner of data mining). So far I have referred many research papers on the same problem domain.

[An Efficient Approach for Clustering Web Access Patterns from
Web Logs](http://www.sersc.org/journals/IJAST/vol5/1.pdf)

[Classifying the user intent of web queries using k-means clustering](http://faculty.ist.psu.edu/jjansen/academic/jansen_user_intent_kmeans.pdf)

I want to use k-means clustering to cluster web pages. Although these papers discuss about the algorithm, they do not specify the way of providing input data set. `k-means` calculate similarity between data points using Euclidean distance. So how to normalize my datset to be mined using `k-means` since urls can not directly used for k-means. Any help/good reference on this?

Example Dataset(p1..pn are different web pages)

```
p1,p2,p3,p4
p1,p2
p1,p5,p6,p7
p1,p2,p3,p5
```

Comment: Have you considered **not** using k-means? K-means is more of a vector quanization method than actually a clustering algorithm... and it absolutely is only useable on vector data, where you want to minimize variance.

Comment: Plus, what *is* a cluster on your data set anyway? Maybe you are actually interested in *frequent itemsets*, instead of clusters?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse : Ok I need both, first to identify frequent item sets, and then to cluster users? I thought of k-means since most have used it in web usage mining, any way it can be any clustering algorithm(no lazy learners) or else I may be develop new one?:) But help me to preprocess these urls for mining?Thanks.

Comment: No, you probably *only* need to identify frequent item sets, then you are done. **What is a cluster**?

Comment: First of all, K-means is used when you know in advance the number of clusters that you want (k clusters). What I understood from your question is that you just want to find similar web pages, and thus you have no knowledge about the number of categories that you need.So unless you are willing to keep trying different k values, k-means is not he best choice to go with. Second, if your data is dense( which is most probably the case for webpages), k-means will perform very poorly if compared with other techniques. So try not to use k-means unless it was part of the requirements.

Comment: Instead, I would go with association rules and get the frequent itemsets as stated by @Anony-Mousse

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Thanks for your comments, I only need to know how to pre-process url data in to a format that I can feed them in to a clustering algorithm,since clustering algorithms use distance calculations?@John Any idea?

Comment: Use random numbers. Then you can cluster them. The results will be meaningless though... Therefore, first think about *what* you want the result to *mean*, then what is the proper approach, then how to represent your data. I don't think you can meaningfully use clustering here.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you have set of webpages and for each of them set of users that have visited them. Eg (0 - not visited, 1 - visited):

```
WebPage  | user1 | user2 | user3
webpage1 |     0 |     1 |     1
webpage2 |     1 |     0 |     0
webpage3 |     0 |     1 |     1
```

and you want do find distances between these web pages.

Then Euclidean distance between two web pages is:
d(wp<sub>1</sub>, wp<sub>2</sub>) = sqrt((u<sub>1,1</sub> - u<sub>2,1</sub>)^2 + (u<sub>1,2</sub> - u<sub>2,2</sub>)^2 + ... + (u<sub>1,n</sub> - u<sub>2,n</sub>)^2), 
 where u<sub>2,1</sub> = 1 if user1 has visited webpage2, otherwise 0

so d(webpage1, webpage2) = sqrt((0 - 1)^2 + (1 - 0)^2 + (1 - 0)^2) = sqrt(3)
d(webpage1, webpage3) = sqrt(0+0+0) = 0 = zero distance between them

you also can for each user take the number of particular web page visits into account, than instead of 1 for visited webpage use weighted values: numberOfParticularWebPageVisits/numberOFAllUsersWebpageVisits

Comment: Hey michal, Thanks a lot for the answer, this is what i needed and by the way I have figured out how to do this.(converting it in to a matrix, similarly what u have done).